# Play a sequence of MIDI notes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, midi

What is the best way to play one note after another?  Here is the most functional bit of code I have right now.

```
    let majorScale = [60, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 71, 72]
    for i in majorScale {
        sampler.startNote(UInt8(i), withVelocity: 127, onChannel: 1)
        sleep(1)
        sampler.stopNote(UInt8(i), onChannel: 1)
    }
```

The problem with this method is that sleep() only takes UInt8 as parameters so I can't make a note last less than 1 second this way.

I'm a musician first and foremost. I just happen to understand a little about programming from back in college when I took a couple java classes.  That said, I don't really know what other options exist.

- Is there some built in MIDI player I could be using to handle note duration?
- Is there a way to "sleep" less than a second, and then calculate the duration myself?  As in a 1/8 note played at 100 bpm would last ((60/100)/2) = 0.3 seconds.
- Should I instead be taking the note information and essentially making a MIDI file that I can then play?

How best to tackle the problem?

EDIT

Here is the updated code:

```
    for i in majorScale {
        sampler.startNote(UInt8(i), withVelocity: 127, onChannel: 1)
        let pause = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        dispatch_after(pause, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.sampler.stopNote(UInt8(i), onChannel: 1)
        }
        sampler.stopNote(UInt8(i), onChannel: 1)
    }
```

So I realized something about this.  I changed the instrument to organ (instead of piano), and it does stop the notes after 1 second, or 10, or whatever I put in there, but it seems like it's going on with the for loop in the meantime, so all the notes are sounding simultaneously instead of in sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help with the midi aspect of this, but as for pausing or sleeping, you should use `dispatch_after`.  Put the following code in place of the sleep(1) and the stopNote call.  This will allow you to perform delays with nano second accuracy. Just change the second parameter of the dispatch_time_t() call to whatever time you need.

```
let pause = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(pause, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        sampler.stopNote(UInt8(i), onChannel: 1)
}
```

Comment: Just because the API accepts units of nanoseconds does not mean the actual implementation can come anywhere near this. See the documentation on dispatch_after. It is best effort and could be significantly longer than requested. For playing music accurately there's surely a better way through a specialized APi

Comment: Ok, so I sort of see what's going on here... but it isn't exactly working.  If I copy the above code it runs, but plays the whole scale in like a split second.  It doesn't seem to be waiting at all.  I substituted 1000 instead of 1 and I got the same result.

Comment: Also to BaseZen, I'm sure you're right... there probably is an API that can handle it, but it was a nightmare getting just to this point.  I would almost prefer using some sort of sleep method. rather than figuring out another set of convoluted APIs.  Apple's documentation on sound processing so spotty, and there isn't much in the way of example code online.

Comment: Post your whole method as it sits right now with the dispatch delay.

Comment: For starters, Remove that stopNote line after the dispatch_after function.  You only need 1.

Comment: And I just found this, it's doing the same thing I suggested but a little cleaner.  The op says it's working for him. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756092/how-do-i-use-the-swift-sampler-to-play-a-tone-then-pause-before-playing-the-next

Answer (score 0):

Try to use timer to control loop through the notes array.
after note play one time, stop the notes when the timer started next time.

```
var playCount = 0   

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.6, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimerContinue), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func fireTimerContinue(){
    var note: Int8 = 0
    if(index < note_array.count){
        note = Int8(note_array[index])
        self.audioEngine.sampler.startNote(UInt8(note), withVelocity: UInt8(velocity), onChannel: 0)

        playCount += 1  
        if playCount > 1 {
            audioEngine.sampler.stopNote(UInt8(note), onChannel: 0)
            playCount = 0
            index = index + 1

        }

      }
  }
```